Pyinstaller .app generated for macos does not run
I have created a tkinter app, used pyinstaller to generate it for Ubuntu and MacOS. It works fine in Ubuntu.
It generates an executable and an .app directory for MacOs. If I run the executable, it runs okay but I get the terminal even though I specified "--noconsole". Looked it up and a StackOverflow answer says to use the .app directory instead.
I copied foo.app to /Applications. Opened up Finder and double-clicked on it. It doesn't work, the GUI doesn't come up (which makes sense, it's a directory).
Found another answer on StackOverflow and it says to try to run  ./dist/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo from the command line in a terminal. I did that it and it works perfectly! The executable inside the Contents/MacOS directory behaves okay.
I tried this:
open dist/foo.app/Contents/MacOS/foo

and I still get the console window. But if I do this:
cd dist/foo.app/Contents/MacOS
./foo

I don't get the console window.
Not sure what to do next, so:

How do I get Finder to run the executable inside the foo.app directory when I double-click on it?

I'm assuming that I need to distribute the foo.app directory.
Is there something else I should distribute?


=== Update
This question is similar:
Pyinstaller app works at terminal but not when double-clicking in finder
His problem was caused by an exception thrown by the app. I checked mine:
cd /Applications/foo.app/Content/MacOS
./foo

No exception thrown.
